# Regular Expression Ends

Tags: regex

I have scoured the web in the past few hours trying to figure out why in the world one of my colleagues insists on using `(?!.)` as a last-character in his regular expressions instead of the usual `$`.

Some of the regular expressions I've seen have been `^.*.txt(?!.)` which begin with the usual `^`, but do not end with the `$`.  I have not been able to find any definitive or time-efficient reasons, any pros and cons or differences at all?

Comment: You should give [TDWTF](http://thedailywtf.com/) a read

Comment: It's a look around, see http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444   (it means no more character) but no need to use it when you just want to use `$`, it's overkill

Comment: have you even asked him?

Comment: ask your colleague.  We don't know why he does what he does

Comment: Of course I have asked, multiple times, even! However, he prefers to be a mysterious and quiet sandwich muncher and not much of a talker.  He said, and I quote, "It's better," but wouldn't go into detail, hence my question.  Thanks for the link, Bojangles!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$` *may* match *end of line* rather than *end of input* (this depends on modifiers used). Perhaps this is the reason.

In my opinion, the best way to match the *end of input* is `\z` - which means exactly end of input, regardless of modifiers. It is supported in most (if not all) regex implementations.

Comment: Ahhh, interesting.  I could see that being a problem in our system as we deal with multiple platforms and multiple languages, so I suppose functional expectation is low -- better be careful on syntax.  Thanks, I didn't know about `\z`.

Answer (score 3):

The only possible difference is with multiline

`asdf$` :
http://rubular.com/r/B2cNEL1pln

`asdf(?!.)` :
http://rubular.com/r/rbhKi1lKGI

Comment: Although perhaps unintentional, you just gave me a good resource: http://www.rubular.com.  Thanks!  This is a great place to test regular expressions.

Comment: @BrainlessBox Damn it! You found out my secret :P

Answer (score 2):

`^.*\.txt(?!.)` means match (beginning)(anything 0 or more times).txt and is not followed by anything.

You can get more info on the `?!` pattern [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28?!pattern%29).

If you look [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers), it says that using the m or s modifiers, you can modify the behavior of ^ and $, to match beginning or end of line, rather than the whole string. There's also an ms. So, I guess with `(?!.)`, you can match the end of the entire multi-line string.

So, I wouldn't say using this is better. Rather, I would say you need to know exactly what you're looking for or what you actually intend to do, within a single-lined string, or multi-lined string and how you want to parse your input to get one-line or multi-line strings, before passing into the regexp.

I think many of us run regexps on single-lined strings and therefore do not feel a difference between the two syntaxes.

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciate the searching, but it seems as though both of us are finding about the same thing -- there is no reason, and my colleague is simply a crazy person.  Do you know if there are any performance differences?

Comment: updated my answer with a little bit more info. Not sure if it auto-triggers you.